# Set of three records forms a record, other set with same data to be identified as Duplicate records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo9cf.jpg)

Header table: MarkupAutoTable

```
RecID  | Name
-------+---------
1000   | Agent1    
1001   | Agent2    
1002   | Agent3
```

Line table: MARKUPAUTOLINE

```
RefRecID   MARKUPCODE   VALUE
--------------------------------
1000       Duty           12
1000       Commission      5
1000       Freight         7
1001       Duty           12
1001       Commission      5
1001       Freight         7
1002       Duty            4.5
1002       Commission      8.8
```

In table data shown above, first three records with column MARKUPCODE and VALUE exactly matches with next three records (in order words 1000 and 1001). Hence we can say those set of three records are duplicate.

I would like to know SQL query to identify such set of duplicate records. Please share SQL query for above scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Dayakar Reddy
Hyderabad India

Thanks f

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL Server with logic such as this:

```
select mua1.RefRecID, mua2.RefRecID
from (select mua1.*, count(*) over (partition by mua1.RefRecID) as cnt
      from MARKUPAUTOLINE mua1
     ) mua1 join
     (select mua2.*, count(*) over (partition by mua2.RefRecID) as cnt
      from MARKUPAUTOLINE mua2
     ) mua2
     on mua1.MARKUPCODE = mua2.MARKUPCODE and
        mua1.VALUE = mua2.VALUE and
        mua1.cnt = mua2.cnt
        mua1.RefRecID < mua2.RefRecID
group by mua1.RefRecID, mua2.RefRecID
having count(*) = mua1.cnt;
```

This does a self-join on the table.  It counts the number of rows in common and makes sure that that matches all the rows for the table.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function createTab () returns INT as $$            
 begin                                                                  
 create table MARKUPAUTOLINE (                                          
   RefRecID int,                                                          
   Markupcode varchar,                                                    
   value int);                                                            
 return 1;END;$$                                                        
 Language plpgsql;
```

> creates table:

```
    select * from createTab();
```

> Inserts into table:

```
create or replace function insertMark(ref int, mark varchar, value int) 
returns void as $$                                                           
  begin                                                                           
   insert into markupautoline values(ref,mark,value);                              
  END;                                                                            
  $$                                                                              
  language plpgsql;
  select insertMark(1000, 'Duty', 12);
  select insertMark(1000, 'Commission', 5);
  select insertMark(1000, 'Freight', 7);
  select insertMark(1001, 'Duty', 12);
  select insertMark(1001, 'Commission', 5);
  select insertMark(1001, 'Freight', 7);
  select insertMark(1002, 'Duty', 4);
  select insertMark(1002, 'Commission', 12);
```

> Selects consecutive duplicates;

```
select a.refrecid,a.markupcode,a.value from 
  (select *,
    (select count(*)
     from markupautoline a2 where abs(a1.refrecid - a2.refrecid) = 1 
     and
     a1.markupcode = a2.markupcode and a1.value = a2.value) as cnt 
  from markupautoline a1) a where a.cnt > 0;

 refrecid | markupcode | value 
----------+------------+-------
     1000 | Duty       |    12
     1000 | Commission |     5
     1000 | Freight    |     7
     1001 | Duty       |    12
     1001 | Commission |     5
     1001 | Freight    |     7 
(6 rows)
```

I assume that order in which records are inserted are as per the refrecid and so refrecid 1000 won't appear after 1001 otherwise you need to order the query by refrecid first. The flow of the query is such, for every row check for rows that has refrecid +1 or -1 and other columns equal, if yes return the row. I hope this helps. Do let me know if there are any other constraints.